# Заменить одномерный массив на двумерный

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

По сути же используется двумерный массив a размером n на m, или же что-то не правильно понимаю? Если же это одномерный, то можете, пожалуйста, подправить, как тогда надо исправить код?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int * a, i, j, n, m;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&m);
    a = (int *) malloc(n*m * sizeof(int));
    if (a==NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            scanf("%d", (a + i*m + j));
    for (j=m-1; j>=0; j--)
        for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
            if (*(a+i*m+j) < 0)
            {
                *(a+i*m+j)=0;
                break;
            }
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            printf("%d\t", *(a+i*m+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас все правильно. Реально работать с двумерными массивам (с учетом их обработки в функциях), размер которых не известен во время компиляции, невозможно. М.б. вам больше понравится вот такой синтаксис для доступа к элементам массива -- `a[i * m + j]` что семантически полностью эквивалентно используемой вами -- `*(a+i*m+j)`

Answer (score 2):

Двумерные массивы можно создавать разными способами, они могут иметь разное представление в памяти, с разным способом доступа и почему-то все программисты называют их одним синонимом - матрицей.
Вы реализовали свою матрицу с индивидуальной функцией доступа. Где адрес каждого элемента вычисляется по *секретной* формуле.
Допустим вы создали матрицу 2x3 и она расположена в памяти так :

```
00 : [0][0]
01 : [0][1]
02 : [0][2]
03 : [1][0]
04 : [1][1]
05 : [1][2]
```

тогда ваша формула доступа `*(a+i*3+j)` будет работать.
Эта формула идентична к представлении матрицы в языке Си и можно сделать так, чтобы формула вычисления элемента была спрятана компилятором. Нужно сделать тип матрицы с фиксированной размерностью.

```
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&m);
typedef int tmNM [ n ] [ m ] ;
```

и выделить память под неё

```
tmNM * a = malloc(sizeof(tmNM));
```

здесь `a` - будет указателем на тип матрицы с фиксированными размерностями и доступ к элементам будет автоматическим вот так :

```
( * a ) [ i ] [ j ]
```

в памяти будет представляться аналогично к вашей программе.

Освобождение памяти :

```
free ( a ) ;
```

---

Другой способ создании матрицы вызван с неудобством передачи типа указателя на матрицу другим функциям. И тогда создают массив указателей на массивы чисел и называют так-же матрицей.

```
int * * a ;
a = malloc (sizeof( int * ) * n) ;
for(int i = 0;i<n;++i)
  a[i] = malloc(sizeof( int ) * m);
```

`a` - будет вектором указателей и доступ к `a[i]` будет иметь значение указателю на массив, который будет выполнять роль строки матрицы.

```
a[0] == & [0][0]
a[1] == & [1][0]
```

и доступ к элементам будет выглядеть так :

```
a[i][j]

& a[i][j] == & a[i][0] + j
```

Освобождение памяти :

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;++i)
  free ( a[i] );
free ( a ) ;
```

Comment: По-моему и не придется объяснять.)У вас лучше получилось.

Answer (score 0):

```
a =(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));     
for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
    a[i] = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int);
}

//Something...
//

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    free(a[i]);
}
free(a);
```

Так, начнем с того, что у вас одномерный массив `n*m`, но в примере (вашем) работаете как бы с двумерной матрицей. Обращение к элементам массива у вас осуществляется `a+i*m+j`,где `a` - указатель на массив, `i` - индекс 1 цикла,внешнего;`m` - количество columns;`j` - индекс 2 цикла, вложенного. Другими словами, "достучаться" до элемента, как в двумерном массиве путем `a[i][j]` - неправильно(выдаст ошибку).

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, что вы имели ввиду, что и как надо изменить?

Comment: По-конкретней: что именно вам не понятно?Вопрос был следующим *как будет выглядеть двумерный массив*. Вам ответил, с объяснением. Уточняйте вопрос.

Comment: Что помимо того, что вы написали надо исправить и на что? Почему-то в ```a[i] = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int);``` выдает ошибку

Comment: Прошу прощения за неудобства. Можете, пожалуйста, помочь, исправить мой код на двумерный, чтобы он работал, а то как-то у меня не получается, буду очень признателен

Comment: Завтра попробую объяснить вам. Время позднее.